# Getting Error with my Automatic ReactJS Music Player after Some Reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a dummy site for side project. When someone visit it plays automatically in the background without clicking on play button. It worked for the first reload and a few reload but after reloading a few times and also uploading to the surge.sh/hosting sites it doesn't auto play until I click on play button.

I can't fix this problem. Please help me.

**What I have tried are following:-**

```
1) componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("load", this.togglePlay);
  }

2)  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("load", this.togglePlay);
  }
```

**My Codes**

```
import React from "react";
import song1 from "../src/resources/song/song1.mp3";

class Music extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { play: false };
    this.url = "http://streaming.tdiradio.com:8000/house.mp3";
    // this.url = song1;

    this.audio = new Audio(this.url);
    this.togglePlay = this.togglePlay.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    setTimeout(() => this.togglePlay(), 1000);
  };

  togglePlay() {
    this.setState({ play: !this.state.play });
    console.log(this.audio);
    this.state.play ? this.audio.play() : this.audio.pause();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui buttons">
        <button onClick={this.togglePlay}>
          {this.state.play ? "Play The Song" : "Pause The Song"}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Music;
```

Song should have automatically played on page load after the set time but it does give me error after a few reloads.

Screenshots of the error that I get:
1)https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDG6n.jpg
2)https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGUYB.jpg

Comment: Does increasing the timeout help?

Comment: No, It doesn't work. I tried.